# Calculating geometric mean of a long list of random doubles

Tags: java, math

So, I came across a problem today in my construction of a restricted Boltzmann machine that should be trivial, but seems to be troublingly difficult. Basically I'm initializing 2k values to random doubles between 0 and 1.

What I would like to do is calculate the geometric mean of this data set. The problem I'm running into is that since the data set is so long, multiplying everything together will always result in zero, and doing the proper root at every step will just rail to 1.

I could potentially chunk the list up, but I think that's really gross. Any ideas on how to do this in an elegant way?

In theory I would like to extend my current RBM code to have closer to 15k+ entries, and be able to run the RBM across multiple threads. Sadly this rules out apache commons math (geometric mean method is not synchronized), longs.

Comment: Number gets super small and I'm looking for a more long-term solution. I plan on trying something similar with a list of close to 15k and I would like a solution that also works with that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Calculation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow, using a big decimal type is way overkill!

Just take the logarithm of everything, find the arithmetic mean, and then exponentiate.

Answer (score 1):

Mehrdad's logarithm solution certainly works.  You can do it faster (and possibly more accurately), though:

1. Compute the sum of the exponents of the numbers, say `S`.
2. Slam all of the exponents to zero so that each number is between `1/2` and `1`.
3. Group the numbers into bunches of at most 1000.

   - For each group, compute the product of the numbers.  This will not underflow.
   - Add the exponent of the product to `S` and slam the exponent to zero.
4. You now have about 1/1000 as many numbers.  Repeat steps 2 and 3 unless you only have one number.
5. Call the one remaining number `T`.  The geometric mean is `T`<sup>1/`N`</sup> 2<sup>`S`/`N`</sup>, where `N` is the size of the input.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on your process here, what exponents are you talking about? Also multiplying 1000 random numbers together will absolutely underflow. On the order of 10^-300. Probably a few orders of magnitude lower.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus:  "Exponent" here means the exponent part of the double---the part that isn't the sign bit or the significand.  Multiplying 1000 doubles between 1/2 and 1 will not underflow since the smallest representable exponent is less than -1000; that's why I picked 1000.

Comment: I believe the smallest exponent is actually on the order of -300. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/53760/, which puts this in danger of underflow, though in smaller batches it would be fine. Have you run benchmarks on this? It's not an elegant solution, but if the performance gains are significant I would be willing to switch. My intuition says it would be slower, but I don't know a huge amount about Java's built in logarithm.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: No, the smallest normal exponent is -1022, which is considerably smaller than -300.  And there are things called subnormals.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point contains some rather useful information about IEEE floating point.  This approach is considerably (65 times on my machine) faster than summing logarithms when implemented properly in C++, and it has the advantage of being (much) more numerically stable.

Comment: It bears mention that my C++ implementation doesn't handle infinities, NaNs, subnormals, or zeros properly.

Comment: For reference, I found out a good way to do  is to `exp( mean / Long.highestOneBit(mean) << 1) * Long.highestOneBit(mean) << 1`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after a sufficient number of multiplications the double precision is not sufficient anymore. Too many leading zeros, if you will.

[The wiki page on arbitrary precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum) shows a few ways to deal with the problem. In Java, BigDecimal seems the way to go, though at the expense of speed.